# reCAPTCHA нужно вставить проверку в ajax запрос

Tags: ajax, recaptcha

У меня есть работающая форма, нужно вставить капчу чтоб без нее форма не отправлялась, следовал примерам документации и других вопросов на данную тему, но не получилось. Ниже фрагмент js и html.

```js
// пример f1: review_nad.noUiSlider.get(),
var review_nad = document.getElementById('review_nad');
if (review_nad) {
  noUiSlider.create(review_nad, {
    start: [7],
    connect: [true, false],
    //  connect: true,
    // tooltips: [ false, wNumb({ decimals: 1 }), true ],
    tooltips: true,
    range: {
      'min': 0,
      'max': 10
    },
    format: wNumb({
      decimals: 1
    })
  });
}

//отправка
$('.send_review').click(function() {
  // TODO: валидацию

  $.ajax({
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      action: 'add_review',
      f1: review_nad.noUiSlider.get(),
      f2: review_design.noUiSlider.get(),
      f3: review_bat.noUiSlider.get(),
      f4: review_quality.noUiSlider.get(),
      f5: review_form.noUiSlider.get(),
      f6: review_ease.noUiSlider.get(),
      final: review_our.noUiSlider.get(),
      review: $('#reviewtext').val()
    },

    success: function(data) {
      if (data[0] == '0') {
        swal("Ошибка", data.substring(1), "error");
      } else {
        swal({
          title: "Благодарим за отзыв!",
          text: data,
          type: "success",
          allowOutsideClick: true,
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tab_conternt' id="review_cam">
  <p class="h_text">Шаг 1. Оцените камеру по каждому критерию</p>
  <div class="range_inps">
    <div class="range_inp">
      <p>Надёжность</p>
      <!--<input type="range" min="0" max="10" /> -->
      <div id="review_nad" class='blue_renge'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="range_inp">
      <p>Video quality</p>
      <!--<input type="range" min="0" max="10" /> -->
      <div id="review_quality" class='blue_renge'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="range_inp">
      <p>Дизайн и форма</p>
      <!--<input type="range" min="0" max="10" /> -->
      <div id="review_design" class='blue_renge'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="range_inp">
      <p>Дизайн и форма</p>
      <!--<input type="range" min="0" max="10" /> -->
      <div id="review_form" class='blue_renge'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="range_inp">
      <p>Батарея</p>
      <!--<input type="range" min="0" max="10" /> -->
      <div id="review_bat" class='blue_renge'></div>
    </div>
    <div class="range_inp">
      <p>Ease or use</p>
      <!--<input type="range" min="0" max="10" /> -->
      <div id="review_ease" class='blue_renge'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="h_text">Шаг 2. Напишите детальный обзор</p>
  <div class="text_rev">
    <textarea name="" id="reviewtext" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder='Введите текст отзыва'></textarea>
    <p><span>Подсказка:</span> Незабудьте включить свои первоначальные мысли об использовании продукта, о любых наблюдениях и, возможно, о любых проблемах, с которвми вы могли столкнуться при использовании. </p>
  </div>
  <p class="h_text">Шаг 3. Поставьте финальную оценку и отправьте Ваш обзор</p>
  <div class="range_inp range_inp100">
    <p>Общая оценка</p>
    <!--<input type="range" min="0" max="10" /> -->
    <div id="review_our" class='blue_renge'></div>
  </div>
  <div class="info_text">
    Мы расчитали общий рейтинг камеры, исходя из среднего значения Ваших критериев, указанных ваше. Вы можете изменить оценку, перетащив ползунок
  </div>
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeAeicUAAAAAHjt7u_Kt8nROx60DYngRV41c75c"></div>
  <a href="#" class="button_green send_review">Отправить</a>
  <!-- rest of the panel content -->
</div>
```